# Send data to every screen in a bottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm coding a Pokemon application with react native. In it, I've a bottomTabNvigator with 4 screens:

- Information
- Evolution
- Places
- Moves

When I select a pokemon in a list, I land on the first screen which give me some information of the pokemon.

On the moves screen I see the moves of the pokemon selected.

On the second screen (Evolution), I see every evolutions of the selected pokemon. I can click on one evolution to go back on the information screen with the updated information.
For this, I use this.props.navigation.navigate with the new pokemon ID in it.

But on every other screens, the pokemon ID is still the first one.

I would like to push the evolved pokemon's id on every screens so the information can also update on the moves and places screen.

Can somebody help me on this please

Comment: You could use redux: https://medium.com/@pavsidhu/using-redux-with-react-native-9d07381507fe

Comment: You can also pass params through navigation and use componentDidUpdate to listen for those changes

Comment: @Reza Ok, I'll use Redux if I don't find a solution

Comment: @AndréPinto Can you explain this solution? Because I already pass the ID in params wheen I'm navigating form evolution to information, but the params are not updated in every screen, only in the one I'm going to with navigation.navigate

Comment: if you are in a tabnavigator, your param probably is on parent level, try using let `dangerouslyGetParent = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent()` to get your data, it's structure is often in an array of states, one for each tab.

Comment: Thx @AndréPinto. With dangerouslyGetParent I can reach out the data I want!

My only question is: If there is the "dangerously" word in the function name, isn't it dangerous to use?

Comment: I thought it was very dangerous at first, but i needed the data, so I tried and so far I haven't encountered any problems. I think they used that word to prevent users from overusing that method.